# PassportJS with NodeJS not returning errors (MEAN stack)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm running a MEAN stack with PassportJS for authentication, and I'm having an issue with my signup module interacting with my Angular controller. Basically, the errorCallback is never called, and I'm not sure how to properly use the Passport done() implementation.

I have a basic signup form that upon submission, calls this request:

```
$http.post('/api/signup', {
  name: $scope.user.name,
  email: $scope.user.email,
  password: $scope.user.password,
  userSince: new Date().now
}).then(
  function successCallback(res) {
    $rootScope.message = 'Account Created';
    console.log('Success'+res);
    console.dir(res,{depth:5});
    $location.url('/signupConf');
  }, function errorCallback(res) {
    $rootScope.message = 'Failure, see console';
    console.log('Error: '+res);
    console.dir(res,{depth:5});
    $location.url('/');
  });
```

With the express route:

```
app.post('/api/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup'),function(req, res) {
        console.log('User: ' + req.user.email);
    });
```

And finally the Passport (adapted from a Scotch.io tut) module, abridged a little:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
  console.log("Signup Request: "+email);

  process.nextTick(function() {
    User.findOne({ 'email' : email }, function(err, user) {

      if (err) { return done(err); }

      // check to see if theres already a user with that email
      if (user) {
        console.log("User not created, already exsists: "+user);
        return done(err, false, {message: 'Username already exsists.'});
      } else {
        // if there is no user with that email
        // create the user
        var newUser = new User();
        //a bunch of data creation here

        newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
            console.log("Sucessfully created: "+newUser);
            return done(null, newUser);
        });
      }
    });    
  });
}));
```

Everything runs fine, users are created corrected, and if a user with a given email exists, a new one isn't written over it. However, no matter what, successCallback is called. When a username already exist, I can see a 401 error in the browser console. When its a bad request (i.e. not all fields filled), a 400 error.

All the server side console.logs work fine, leading me to think there's something wrong in my angular frontend, or how the backend is responding to the request.

(Scotch.io tutorial credit: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sort of staring me in the face, it was in my route handling.

```
app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err,user,response) {
    //handle responses based on state of user and err
  })
  (req, res, next);
});
```